# how to select 2nd h2 without using class or id? jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I have a script that I need the class for, because I will be changing the class.

Is there a way I can select the .date class (h2) without actually using the class?

```
<div id="sortcontainer">
<li class="game" id="45">
    <a class="gamelink" href="link">
      <img class="image" src="games_category_placeholder.jpg">
      <h2 class="title">Some game</h2>
      <h2 class="date" id="2017">(2017)</h2>
      <h3 class="thumbrating">45/100</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Heres what i have but its not working with an nth selector.
When I replace with .date it works.

```
$('#datereleased').on('click', function(){
  var $sortContainer = $('#sortcontainer');

  $sortContainer.append(
    $sortContainer.children().sort(function(a, b){
      return (
        parseInt($("h2:nth-child(2)", b).attr('id'), 10)
        -
        parseInt($("h2:nth-child(2)", a).attr('id'), 10)
      );

    }).get()
  );
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-of-type` css selector.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('#sortcontainer .gamelink h2:nth-of-type(2)')
);
```

```html
<div id="sortcontainer">
  <li class="game" id="45">
    <a class="gamelink" href="link">
      <img class="image" src="games_category_placeholder.jpg">
      <h2 class="title">Some game</h2>
      <h2 class="date" id="2017">(2017)</h2>
      <h3 class="thumbrating">45/100</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou, working. So with :nth selectors does it only go one level deep?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type  It works amongst siblings.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the `.eq()` method, used to filter the current collection of elements by it's index in the collection.

```
$(a).find('h2').eq(1).attr('id') //note that the first element is 0
```

Also, element collections can be referenced by a zero-indexed array of the jQuery object:

```
$(a).find('h2')[1].id
```

In this case, the DOM element is being used rather than a jQuery object.

Documentation for `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq/